# Unable to connect to SQL Server Error: 26 - Error Locating server/ Instance Specified

Tags: sql-server, connection

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server but I'm unable to do so, and instead I get this error:

[image]

On my SQL Server machine, there are two server instances - one is `DESKTOP-GH4DT15\MSSQLSERVER01` and the second is `DESKTOP-GH4DT15 (MSSQLSERVER)` and I can't connect to either of them:

[image]

All my related services are running for `DESKTOP-GH4DT15\MSSQLSERVER01` but still I'm unable to connect

[image]

For `DESKTOP-GH4DT15\MSSQLSERVER` I'm unable to start the service as I get this error:

[image]

In SQL Server Configuration Management the services are enabled for `DESKTOP-GH4DT15\MSSQLSERVER01`

[image]

But for the `DESKTOP-GH4DT15\MSSQLSERVER` I'm getting another error:

[image]

I'm unable to understand why these error are happening and for the `DESKTOP-GH4DT15\MSSQLSERVER01` all the services are enabled but I'm still unable to connect to that instance.

I need help understanding this issue I tried to solve it by watching YouTube videos but the result was the same. Kindly someone help me resolve these errors.

Comment: Any difference if you replace the machine name with a period `.` ?

Comment: You should consult the ERRORLOG file for the instance that's failing to start to see why that's the case. (If it was working previously then potentially the master/model/msdb files have moved or are residing on a volume that's out of disk space.) You should be able to find out where that ERRORLOG file is by looking at the startup properties of the MSSQLSERVER instance via the SQL Server Configuration Manager tool.